# Is it possible to have a variable span multiple lines in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a very long regex that I would like to put into a variable to test with. I'd like to be able to put it on multiple lines so that it's not so unreadable. I saw you could do multiple lines with the documentation tag. But when I try this formatting, Robot seems to think this is a list. Is there a way to do this in Robot Framework?

Consider:

```
${example_regex} =      '(?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\nSetting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\nSetting IP forwarding kernel options'
```

I would like to be able to write:

```
${example_regex}   '(?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\n
                     Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\n
                     Setting IP forwarding kernel options'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Robot Framework 2.9 added support for multiline literal strings per [the docs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table).

#### `test.robot`

```
*** Variables ***
${example_regex} =  SEPARATOR=
...  (?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\n
...  Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\\n
...  Setting IP forwarding kernel options

*** Test Cases ***
Show output
    Log  \n${example_regex}  console=yes
```

#### `robot test.robot`

```
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Show output
(?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\nSetting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\nSetting IP forwarding kernel options
Show output                                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

A few notes:

- All leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed from each line
- A plain `SEPARATOR=` in the first line specifies no separator

You may also consider using [variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) since then you get all the power of Python literal formatting, which can make maintaining things like complicated regular expressions easier. If you're using Robot Framework 3+ and Python 3.5+ (for `f`-strings) then it can look like:

#### `vars.py`

```python
ip_address_pattern = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
lower_mac_address_pattern = '[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}'
example_regex = (
  rf'(?m)Setting IP address to {ip_address_pattern}\n'
  rf'Setting MAC address to {lower_mac_address_pattern}\n'
    'Setting IP forwarding kernel options'
)
```

#### `test.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  vars.py

*** Test Cases ***
Show output
    Log  \n${example_regex}  console=yes
```

Which results in the same output as above.

Answer (score 33):

### In a Variables table

If you are creating the strings in a `*** Variables ***` table, you can spread the definition across multiple lines. You can use a special argument `SEPARATOR` to define how the cells are joined together. By default the lines are joined by a space, so you'll want to set it to the empty string by explicitly not giving `SEPARATOR` a value.

See [Variable table](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table) in the user guide for more information.

```
*** Variables ***
${example_regex}=  SEPARATOR=
...  (?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\n
...  Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\\n
...  Setting IP forwarding kernel options
```

### In a test case or keyword

If you are trying to do this in a test case or keyword, you can't directly define a multiline string. However, you can get the same effect using the [catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0.1/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) keyword in a test case or keyword to join data which is spread across multiple cells. Be sure to properly escape your backslashes, and set the separator character to an empty string if you don't want newlines in the data.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Multiline variable example
  ${example_regex}=  catenate  SEPARATOR=
  ...  (?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\n
  ...  Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\\n
  ...  Setting IP forwarding kernel options
  log  regex: '${example_regex}'
```

Comment: This is a very useful technique. My variable required the use of the ${SPACE} variable to force a space character at the end of a line.

Comment: For those who want to have a newline, putting `\n` or `${\n}` in the text works.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to **Robot Framework 2.9** python's [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) function could be used:

```
*** Variables ***

@{example_regex}=
...  (?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\n
...  Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}\n
...  Setting IP forwarding kernel options'

*** Test Cases ***

MultiLine
  ${example_regex}=  Evaluate  "".join(${example_regex})
  Log  "\n"${example_regex}
```

Result:

```
20190813 14:02:39.421 - INFO - ${example_regex} = (?m)Setting IP address to [0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}
Setting MAC address to [0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}:[0-9a-f]{2}
Setting IP forwarding kernel option...
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing multiple line in input text through robot framework-

```
***Test cases***
input text   locater_here   Text_you_want_write${\n}
input text   locater_here   good morning${\n}
```

This is how you shift a sentence to a new line by using "${\n}"